# ActiveRecord querying through multiple joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord

So below are my models:

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  has_many :collectables
  has_many :collections, through: :collectables
end
```

**tagging.rb**

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :tag, counter_cache: :posts_count
end
```

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :posts, through: :taggings
end
```

**collectable.rb**

```
class Collectable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :collection, counter_cache: :posts_count
end
```

**collection.rb**

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collectables
  has_many :posts
end
```

A Collection has many Posts, and a Post has many Tags. Now I'm trying to create a search bar that'll search for *Collections* by Posts that have particular *Tags* (`tag.name` is the search term). For instance, Collection 1 has a post that has the tag #cat. Now if the user searches for "cat", Collection 1 will show up in the results. I'm not sure how the query should look like for making this happen.

```
def self.search(search)
  Collection.joins(:posts) ... ?
end
```

Comment: `Collections.joins(posts: :tags).where(tags: {name: search_term})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
def self.search(search)
  Collection.includes(posts: :tags).where(tags: {name: search})
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
def self.search(search)
    Collection.joins(posts: :tags).where({tags: {name: search}})
end
```

You can use includes, eager_load and joins, but when you use joins then only it will take those collections who have the posts in all other cases, it will take all collections who have the posts and who don't have the posts.